# Loop through all columns in Bash

Tags: bash, csv

My goal is to read a .csv file, reverse each row, and then write out the result to another file and I successfully managed to do that.

The problem with my code is that I had to specify the number of columns in my csv file (f1, f2, f3, etc). How can I make it go through all columns without specifying the number of columns in a scenario where I don't know the content of the  .csv file?

PS: I did try searching for an answer on the forum before asking but I really couldn't find anything that helps!

```
input="/path/to/file"
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do 
    echo "$f7 $f6 $f5 $f4 $f3 $f2 $f1" >> output.csv
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Small improvement: write `>> output.csv` outside the while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **`awk`** not only makes dealing with a variable number of columns easier, but will also be **much faster**:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=NF; i>=2; --i) printf "%s ", $i; print $1 }' "$input" > output.csv
```

- `-F,` tells `awk` to split the input into fields by commas
- `for(i=NF; i>= 2; --i)` loops over all fields indices, counting down from `NF` (the number of input fields) to the *2nd* field.
- `$i` references field (column) whose (1-based) index is `i`.
- `printf "%s "` is the (implicit) loop body (you may enclose it in `{ ... }` for clarity), and it prints the field at hand with a trailing space, as in your question's code.
  Note that `printf`, unlike `print` does *not* automatically append a newline by default.
- Finally, after the loop, `print $1` prints the *first* field, followed by a newline (`\n`) to complete the output line (`\n` is the default value for `ORS`, the output record separator).

---

If you need a **pure Bash solution** (**much slower**):

[Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) combined with `read -a` are the solution:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do # read input line by line
  # Split line into fields and read into array.
  IFS=, read -ra fields <<<"$line"
  # Loop over fields from the back, down to the 2nd.
  for (( i = ${#fields[@]} - 1; i >= 1; --i )); do
    printf '%s ' "${fields[i]}"
  done
  # Print 1st field and complete line (append line).
  printf '%s\n' "${fields[0]}"
done < "$input" > output.csv
```

Note:

- A ***single* output redirection, `> output.csv`, is applied to the *entire loop*** (just like the *input* redirection, `< "$input"`), which is both simpler and more efficient than using `>> output.csv` *inside* the loop (in the latter case, you'd also have to truncate `output.csv` beforehand in order to ensure that no preexisting content is appended to).
- **`bash` arrays are `0`-based**, whereas `awk`-based arrays start at index `1`.